# Can a J2 visa holder work remotely for a french company without applying for an EAD?

Tags: visas, usa, j1-visas

I will work in the USA with a J1 Trainee VISA and my husband is coming with me. He wants to keep working for his french company by working remotely for them, from the USA. Is it possible? Does he have to apply for an EAD?